# SQL Stored Procedure How to Modify and Return the Result of an Executed Dynamic Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that returns a single string of concatenated fields. The issue is that some of these fields may be empty strings resulting in a string much like the below:

```
, Mendip Road, Farnborough, Hampshire, GU14 9LS
```

or even

```
, , Farnborough, Hampshire, GU14 9LS
```

I really want to strip off any leading commas but I'll only know this once the query has been executed. Is there a way of executing the query, pattern-matching the commas and then removing them before finally returning the modified string?

The query itself is as follows:

```
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE((ISNULL(POI,'''') + '', '' + ISNULL(Name,'''') + '', '''
+ ' + ISNULL(Settlement,'''') + '', '' + ISNULL(Cou_Unit,'''') + '', '' + ISNULL(Postcode,'''')),'', , '', '', '')'
+ ' AS ClosestAddress FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] ORDER BY '
+ ' (Longitude ' + @LongitudeOperator + ' ' + CAST(ABS(@Longitude) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'
+ ' * (Longitude ' + @LongitudeOperator + ' ' + CAST(ABS(@Longitude) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'
+ ' + (Latitude - ' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') * (Latitude - ' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') ASC'


EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: Good point... However, I'm just returning an on-screen 'friendly looking' address to the end-user... Commas would confuse them into thinking the app had some error.

Comment: In that case, why not deal with this in the presentation layer?  It can be done in SQL bit you'll run into issues when one ui control displays it one way and another wants something slightly different and is stuck with a string instead of a class/data structure

Comment: Good point but there's a two step process here. Firstly, I need to achieve the fastest speed possible to display a list as it is used as part of a type-ahead input. So this first query's job is to simple return a list of friendly addresses and their database Identifiers - both are then used to fill the address suggestion list. The presentation for this will always be consistent. When the user selects an address and proceeds a further lookup interrogates the database to return all fields from which the developer can then format as they wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the comma inside the ISNULL expression as follows:

```
ISNULL(POI + ', ','')
```

so your query will look like:

```
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE((ISNULL(POI + '', '','''') + ISNULL(Name + '', '','''')'
+ ' + ISNULL(Settlement + '', '','''') + ISNULL(Cou_Unit + '', '','''') + ISNULL(Postcode,'''')),'', , '', '', '')'
+ ' AS ClosestAddress FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] ORDER BY '
+ ' (Longitude ' + @LongitudeOperator + ' ' + CAST(ABS(@Longitude) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'
+ ' * (Longitude ' + @LongitudeOperator + ' ' + CAST(ABS(@Longitude) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'
+ ' + (Latitude - ' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') * (Latitude - ' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') ASC'
```

Comment: Nice simple solution that works perfectly as supplied.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you need dynamic SQL for some other reason, but I think something like this should work (with no Dynamic SQL); if you're really sure you need Dynamic SQL for some other reason, then just refactor this idea into your Dynanmic Statement:

```
DECLARE @ClosestAddress VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT TOP 1 
        @ClosestAddress = ISNULL(POI + ', ','')  
        + ISNULL(Name + ', ','')
        + ISNULL(Settlement + ', ','')
        + ISNULL(Cou_Unit + ', ', '')
        + ISNULL(Postcode,'')
        --AS ClosestAddress 
FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] ORDER BY  (Longitude = 12.2132) * (Longitude = 12.2132) + (Latitude - 12.2132) * (Latitude - 12.2132) ASC

IF (RIGHT(@ClosestAddress, 2) = ', ')
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@ClosestAddress, 0, LEN(@ClosestAddress))
ELSE
    RETURN @ClosestAddress
```

Why this should work: Concatenating `NULL + ', '` will result in an empty string.  Then we check if the string ends with `', '`, and if so we return everything but the last two characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like Replace all Comma with space and then do LTRIM and RTRIM and replace all space with comma.

```
Create table Data(name varchar(10),lastname varchar(10));

insert into Data values('','Doe');

insert into Data values('Jane','Doe');

insert into Data values('Jane','');

SELECT Replace(Rtrim(Ltrim(Replace(ISNULL(name,'') +',' + ISNULL(lastname,'') + ',',',',' '))),' ',',')
 from Data
```

something like : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a6c6/1

Comment: @ChrisCurrie .. Here is an updated version. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52cdb/3   This one replace all the spaces in fields with * and replace all the * with spaces later

Comment: Nice. That also does the job.